# Add UIView at the top of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

I have a `UITableView` and view above it. Sometimes I have a lot of content so this header should be scrolled up and have to be immediatelly shown when I scroll down (like Facebook app). And I have a pull to refresh control so when I pulled down to pull to refresh my header `UIView` should be above `UITableView` (if I use a `UITableViewHeader`it moves down with UITableView). What can you advice? I've really stucked. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out this lib [TLYShyNavBar](https://github.com/telly/TLYShyNavBar)

Comment: I suppose section header is out of the question because it wont vanish when you scroll down ?

Comment: @Abdul91 Yes, you are right

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragama mark delegate UIScrollView   
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self scrollViewAnimation:scrollView];

}
-(void)scrollViewAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{


if (scrollView==YourtableViewName) {
    [YourtableViewName layoutIfNeeded];
    if ([scrollView.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:scrollView.superview].y > 0) {
        NSLog(@"Scrolling Up");
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            viewTop_topConstraint.constant = 0;
            [self.view updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        }];

    } else if ([scrollView.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:scrollView.superview].y < 0) {
        NSLog(@"Scrolling Down");
        if (dataArray.count>4) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
                viewTop_topConstraint.constant = -120;
                [self.view updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
                [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            }];
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a little to implement what you wanted. And I came up with this piece of code. But you might have to do a few tweaks yourself. I just set `sectionHeight` variable to 60 and used that to return that as section height. Make sure you set this variable to 60 (or the height of  your view) in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` method. And `return` the `UIView` you want to show above your `UITableView` in `viewForHeaderInSection` method. Let me know if you have any confusions regarding the code.

```
#pragma mark - TableView Data Source Events

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 50;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"DeliveryPackageCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }


    cell.textLabel.text = @"1";

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - TableView Delegate Events

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return 60;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width,sectionHeight)];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    return view;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return sectionHeight;
}

#pragma mark - Srcoll View Delegates

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    self.initialContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    self.previousContentDelta = 0.f;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat prevDelta = self.previousContentDelta;
    CGFloat delta = scrollView.contentOffset.y - self.initialContentOffset;
    if (delta > 0.f && prevDelta <= 0.f) {
        // started scrolling positively

        if(sectionHeight != 0)
        {
            sectionHeight = 0;
            [tableView reloadData];
        }



    } else if (delta < 0.f && prevDelta >= 0.f) {
        // started scrolling negatively
        if(sectionHeight == 0)
        {
            sectionHeight = 60;
            [tableView reloadData];
        }

    }
    self.previousContentDelta = delta;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But really bad when scrolling - a lot of table refreshes. And after some scrolling app crashes.

Comment: hmmmm, app crashed due to memory ? Above table is only reloaded once after each direction change. This shouldn't be the case.

Comment: And in your code header didn't scroll top slowly. Immediatelly dissapears. :(